# ¿Como acoplar un Store Procedure en Generic handler en vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedure

Quisiera saber cual es la forma mas optima de acoplar un store procedure para insertar un pdf.
Este es mi Generic Handler que solo guarda los archivos en una ruta especifica.

Aun no tengo hecho el store procedure porque necesito mas parametros , solo quiero saber cual es la forma de Acoplar un store con los datos que obtengo de js

[image]

Este es mi código Completo

```
 Imports System
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Net
    Imports System.Web
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Configuration
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
    Imports System.Web.Services
    
    Public Class GenericHandler : Implements IHttpHandler
        'Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler
        Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    
    
            Dim chunk As Integer = If(context.Request("chunk") IsNot Nothing, Integer.Parse(context.Request("chunk")), 0)
            'Dim fileName As String = If(context.Request("name") IsNot Nothing, context.Request("name"), String.Empty)
    
            Dim fileName As String = context.Request.Files(0).FileName
            Dim fileUpload As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files(0)
            Dim uploadPath = context.Server.MapPath("~\DocumentosPrueba")
            Using fs = New FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName),
                If(chunk = 0, FileMode.Create, FileMode.Append))
                Dim buffer = New Byte(fileUpload.InputStream.Length - 1) {}
                fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    
    
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            End Using
    
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
            context.Response.Write("Success")
    
    
    
        End Sub
    
    
    
        Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
            Get
                Return False
            End Get
        End Property
    
    End Class
```

La información del archivo lo obtengo del plugin Filepond
[image]

Comment: Favor trata de usar código como texto,revisa [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)